# Ubuntu can't detect my second monitor

Tags: display, monitor

I know that there were already several people with the same problem, but I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem myself.
I am a complete beginner with Linux and Ubuntu (I am using 12.04) and would like to connect a second monitor to my PC. The first monitor has a HDMI cable and the second on a VGA. When I connect the VGA monitor it works and I get a mirror of the first one. The problem is just, that I can't find the monitor under "Displays" in "Settings". I would like to use it as a additional monitor and not for mirroring.

If I understood it right, then my computer has Intel graphics
(VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06))

I read somewhere that I should try typing in "udevadm monitor" into the terminal and then unplugg the second monitor. If I do that I get the following message:

"KERNEL[1056.880278] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)
UDEV  [1056.883871] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0 (drm)"

Not sure at all what that means.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: And nothing happens if I press detect displays!